# Replace app.config item node value in powershell

Tags: powershell, app-config

Having the following app.config:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
 <add key="filepath" value="D:\Data" />
 <add key="node2" value="..." />
 ...
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want to replace the setting that has 'filepath' key with a new value (by replacing 'D:\Data..' in this case). The new value should be passed as a parameter to the powershell script. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update based on the comment:

```
$xml = [xml]'<configuration>
<appSettings>
 <add key="filepath" value="D:\Data" />
 <add key="filename" value="test.log" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>'

$xml.configuration.appSettings.add | foreach { if ($_.key -eq 'filepath') { $_.value = "C:\Data" } }
$xml.Save("C:\dell\NewApp.config")
```

===========================================================================================

## OLD ANSWER

```
$xml = [xml]'<configuration>
<appSettings>
 <add key="filepath" value="D:\Data" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>'

$xml.configuration.appSettings.add.value = "C:\Data"
$xml.Save("NewApp.config")
```

or

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content App.config)
$xml.configuration.appSettings.add.value = "C:\Data"
$xml.Save("NewApp.Config")
```

Comment: I get the following error: property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable. Seems like I need somehow to tell it to find appSetting's 'filepath' node?

Comment: Well, then you see to have more than one <Add> nodes in the configuration. Correct? If so, please update your question with a sample that has more add nodes.

Comment: The updated answer really saved me many hours, and possible recreation of entire project. But one error (though not stopping me in anyway at this moment) that am getting at this moment is "Cannot convert value to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument""

Appreciate @ravikanth if you can help me with this.